# Type Error: "'types.GenericAlias' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, typeerror

I am working on a project is to convert text into numbers. (For example, "hello world" would be converted to "8 5 12 12 15 27 23 15 18 12 4").

In line 10 of my code, the for loop causes the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabri\PycharmProjects\padding\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    converter(plaintext)
  File "C:\Users\gabri\PycharmProjects\padding\main.py", line 10, in converter
    for n in plaintext:
TypeError: 'types.GenericAlias' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code is as follows:

```
alphabet = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m",'n',"o","p","q","r",'s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')


def getplaintext():
    global plaintext
    plaintext = list[input("Enter plaintext:.....")]
    print(plaintext)

def converter(plaintext):
    for n in plaintext:
        print(n)


getplaintext()
converter(plaintext)
```

Does anybody know what is causing this error?

Answer (score 13):

You need to use `list` with `()`, not `[]`.

```
plaintext = list(input("Enter plaintext:....."))  # With ()
```

In newer versions of Python, container types such as `list` [can be hinted directly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) to specify the type of the elements the container holds. By using square braces here, you create a generic type hint of a list (a "generic alias"). A generic alias for a list is not iterable, as it is not actually a list. This is what causes your error.

Comment: This may be a typo, but I thought that it should be answered. This is a new error in Python, so we'll likely start seeing questions about it.

Comment: Good point about such typos possibly occurring more often. Do you think the question could do with a cleanup to work as a canonical?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was actually thinking that. I'd have to play around with the errors a bit, but I imagine the `types.GenericAlias` will be a common denominator in errors where square braces are used, so focus can be shifted towards it. What's the procedure for that? Does a Meta post need to be made first?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no need for a meta post. I've added this question in the [sopython canonicals](https://sopython.com/canon/141/type-error-types-genericalias-object-is-not-after-using-instead-of-on-a-containe/), which are used by the people in the [rooms/6/python chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). It would be nice if the OP actually accepted your answer, though. :/

Comment: @GabrielReed If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark next to it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)